# Can django-model-utils StatusModel provide human readable status options?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to use the [StatusModel feature](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-model-utils/src#statusmodel) of Carl Meyer's awesome [django-model-utils](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-model-utils) package to create a model that has a status field. It's a very nice design in which you subclass your model from `StatusModel` and pass a `Choices` object to a field on the model called STATUS, which automatically creates 'status' and 'status_changed' fields on the database representation.

I would like for my status field to have a separate human-readable value than its database representation, and the [documentation for the `Choices` class](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-model-utils/src#choices) says that it can be passed a two-tuple in which the first value is the database representation of the choice and the second is the human-readable value. But when I try doing this with my StatusModel using the above `Choices` object, I still get the database representation when I use the status field in a template.

Here's an excerpt of my model class:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from model_utils import Choices
from model_utils.models import StatusModel

STATUS_CHOICES = Choices(
    ('awaiting_approval', _('Awaiting approval')), 
    ('returned_to_submitter', _('Returned to submitter')), 
    ('approved', _('Approved')), 
    ('denied', _('Denied')),
)

class Petition(StatusModel):
    STATUS = STATUS_CHOICES
    ...
```

and here's my template:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    {% for petition in petitions %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ petition.status }}</td> 
        <!-- expecting "Awaiting approval" but it displays "awaiting_approval" -->
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

How do I get the model class to return the human readable status? Or does `StatusModel` not support that feature of the `Choices` object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use the normal `get_FOO_display()` method - in this case `{{ petition.get_status_display }}`

Comment: you can read more in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display